# Delete line in a cell if contains in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, text

Good Morning Everyone,

Simple question on #excel, but can't figure it out. Inside a single cell, i need a #vba to delete lines (they are separated from each other with line breaks) with a given string.

In my example i need to delete line ending with a semicolon ":"

**Input**

```
aaaaaaaaa:11111

bbbbbbbbb:222222222

cccccc:

dddddddddddddddd:33
```

**Output**

```
aaaaaaaaa:11111

bbbbbbbbb:222222222

dddddddddddddddd:33
```

I highly appreciate your help,
Juxe

Answer (score 0):

Have a try on below codes. Assuming you sample texts are in `A` cell.

```
Sub DelLine()
Dim strSplit
Dim Result As String

strSplit = Split(Range("A1"), Chr(10))

    For i = LBound(strSplit) To UBound(strSplit)
        If Right(Trim(strSplit(i)), 1) <> ":" Then
            Result = Result & strSplit(i) & Chr(10)
        End If
    Next

Range("B1") = Result
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Harun! Thanks for your answer and that's indeed exactly what i need. However can't loop it for each cell in colomn A. What should i add? Cheers